# Breaker tripping wires disconnected

Tags: electrical

I ran a new supply line to my pool pump from a 20 amp breaker with 12 ga. UF-B romex out of my attic, down 14 ft. of 1/2 inch conduit on the side of my house then 2 ft below grade, another 40 foot not in conduit, then up to a switch in conduit. My breaker keeps tripping about every 3 days, even with the switch disconnected. Is it due to overheating from running in too small conduit at 90 bend going into attic? Nothing else is on the circuit. I replaced the breaker, thinking it was defective.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Is this a GFCI breaker? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Does the breaker have a TEST button on it?  Also, why the mixture of "conduit" and "not conduit"?

Comment: @threephaseel Outside the house below 8’ requires protection as I read code. The OP did this correctly but 1/2 “ probably cut the insulation.

Comment: OP, did you pull this UF cable through the pre-assembled conduit, or did you assemble the conduit around the wire?  Calcs say #12UF is .463" in the long dimension, giving 214 kcmil.  One "wire" can't exceed 53% fill.  That requires a pipe of 414 kcmil or  0.636" across.  Too big for 1/2" conduit by the book.

Comment: @EdBeal -- agreed that below 8' requires physical prot.  I was more thinking that this would have been just as easy to run as 1/2" conduit (PVC outside, ENT inside) all the way, then the OP would probably have needed less...choice vocabulary for the wire pulling ;)

Comment: I fully agree with conduit the entire length, much easier to pull and looks better. Guessing it is a portable pool also because an In-ground would normally require conduit.

Answer (score 1):

The conduit size will not affect the current, you probably have skinned the insulation and that will cause tripping like you have if the breaker is a GFCI. If a non-GFCI the skinned part is much worse but could still be the cause.

I would get a megger (high voltage ohm meter). I have seen hand crank meggers for around $100 this would probably be cheaper than having an electrician check it.  You disconnect the hot from the breaker and put 1 megger lead on the hot 1 on the ground and crank, with the switch turned off or disconnected the reading should be high 100 mega ohms. If it is low - 10k or less - you have damaged insulation.

I have seen this many times as you found pulling the #12 UF in conduit is a real chore. I am surprised you got it in 1/2", but both metallic and pvc conduit can easily skin the wire and cause the problem you are having.

Most folks don't realize conduit needs to be chamfered to reduce insulation damage when pulling.

Answer (score 0):

Overheating in conduit isn't the issue, you're allowed 3 maxed-out circuits in 1 conduit before you even need to start worrying about thermal derate.

It seems clear that you have a GFCI breaker, because if a plain breaker was tripping, it would have to be making something *rather hot*.  Also it had better be GFCI protected!

We don't know if the ground fault is in the wire, or the pump itself. **The ground fault can be either hot-ground or neutral-ground, and you haven't tested the second one.  I would disconnect the neutral wire at the switch, so both hot and neutral are disconnected from the pump.  Then give it a week.

If it fails to trip, that means the fault is probably past the switch, either in wiring to the pump, or the pump itself.  Divide and conquer by reconnecting, and then disconnecting somewhere farther downline.  Be prepared for it to be the pump.  They are notorious for ground faults.

Comment: The op said it was tripping when disconnected so it is in the wire.